How do i uninstall zed editor from my ubuntu 24
I installed it with these steps:
curl https://zed.dev/install.sh | sh
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
I am running ubuntu 24. need help to uninstall zed.
I tried apt remove but it doesn't work. also, searched over internet didn't get any help.

Since you did not install with apt you can not remove with apt. Look at the contents of the .sh file and see what it does. Would be a good idea to post the contents of that file if you want help to understand what it does. BTW If you are really running Ubuntu 24 that is a Ubuntu Core version number. If not running Ubuntu Core please correct the version info.

It would be a really good idea not to curl random sites into sh. I guess it's the official installation method on the site but it's still gross.

You choose to manually install third party software. Any third party software can have a different procedure to install software. Third party software may or may not include a tool to remove the program. Bottom line: you are totally dependent on the documentation (if any) of that third party software in order to learn how you an remove the software.
In your case, you installed using a script from the internet. This can be very dangerous, so one should make sure the script is from a reputable source, and, even when it is, inspect the code before running it. Now, you could inspect the code of the script to see what it did, then see whether you manually can undo what the script did.
There is a positive side here: the script was run as normal user, so any installed files will be in your home directory. You will be able to remove the files without acting as root, and without risking to break your system.
I briefly took a look at the script. Based on what it did, this is how you can remove everything:

It installed a symbolic link to the executable in ~/.local/bin: remove it with:
rm $HOME/.local/bin/zed # remove symlink to the executable

It installed a .desktop launcher in $HOME/.local/share/applications/. The name is dev.zed.Zed.desktop, or at least starts with dev.zed.Zed. Delete that file.

It created a directory "$HOME/.local/zed.app (or zed*.app depending on the version) and unpacked installation files in there. Delete that directory and its contents.

Finally, you added the line export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH to your ~/.bashrc file. Open that file with a text editor and delete that line.



Thanks for the tutorial! Had just the same issue today, was recommended by some blogs but it does not work properly on Ubuntu-based distros yet?

Is this answer autogenerated? This app was NOT installed from snap, and this is the source of the issue.

@Sklavit no, just general information. But I agree: the answer can do without that first paragraph. I will remove it.

This should be helpful. I have tried all the general method.. but this works
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zed-industries/zed/82ad7f2b/script/install.sh | sh -s uninstall

